# How to upgrade pgAdmin 4 on macos?

Tags: macos, pgadmin

I installed pgAdmin 4 as part of the postgres installer for MACOS. pgAdmin is now telling me there is a newer version.

However, there is no built in upgrade functionality in pgadmin 4.

Can someone help on this matter?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
brew upgrade --cask pgadmin4
```

Works all the time.

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't even know it had a brew cask - too easy...

Comment: I litterally uninstalled and reinstalled through homebrew just to be able to update this way 

Answer (score 3):

You can reinstall a new pgadmin here:

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/

Answer (score 0):

I've [installed](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/pgadmin4) [pgadmin](/questions/tagged/pgadmin) once via [homebrew](/questions/tagged/homebrew), and everytime I've done `brew upgrade` and there's been an update its installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I go directly to the [pgAdmin download page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/). Then I install it just like any other Mac program (dragging into the Applications folder).

Be sure to close all connections and shut down the server before installing.

Note: For me, this is in a folder within my Applications folder called "PostgreSQL 11" Not sure if this was by design or a mistake on my part.

Answer (score -1):

If you installed via the download online for the macOS App Bundle containing the pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime and Web application via [enter link description here](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-macos/), then you just have to close the app if it is open and reinstall the newest (or version of your choice) over your current version and you are good to go when you start up the new version.